# Conflito com nome de MBean ao subir duas aplicações Spring Boot no mesmo Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Tenho duas aplicações em Spring Boot que usam uma nomenclatura comum para os *beans*. No caso, meu *pool* de conexões com o banco é gerenciada pelo HikariCP.

Devido a um problema de infraestrutura, precisei subir dois dos meus projetos Spring Boot no mesmo Tomcat. Ao tentar fazer isso, o Tomcat me retorna esse erro:

> ```
> org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig@60a88c19] with key 'myHikariConfig'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.zaxxer.hikari:name=myHikariConfig,type=HikariConfig
>   at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:628) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:550) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:432) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:781) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>   ... 37 frames omitidos
> Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.zaxxer.hikari:name=myHikariConfig,type=HikariConfig
>   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>   at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>   at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>   at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>   at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>   at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:195) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:674) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:618) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>   ... 42 common frames omitted
>
> 2018-04-18 16:09:08.482  INFO 1412 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@271c4: startup date [Wed Apr 18 16:08:51 GFT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
> 2018-04-18 16:09:08.482  INFO 1412 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
> ```

Eu sei que eu poderia tratar renomeando os *beans* de ambos os projetos para não se chocarem, mas existem diversos outros *beans* que também seguem o padrão de nomenclatura, assim como existem outros aplicativos em Spring Boot aqui na empresa que, ocasionalmente, vamos precisar subir (possivelmente) no mesmo Tomcat.

Então, tem como isolar cada aplicação para ter uma espécie de "*namespace*" de de *beans* no Spring? Se sim, como?

Procuro uma alternativa que minimize alterações no código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem sim. Através da configuração do nome de domínio JMX você consegue uma espécie de "isolamento" ao definir um **nome de domínio JMX**. Você pode verificar a propriedade [`spring.jmx.default-domain` na documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html). [Esta resposta no SO internacional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48231073/4438007) exemplifica como tratar isso.

No caso, só precisei definir para cada aplicação um nome de domínio JMX diferente, não sendo necessário **nenhuma outra ação**. Eu só precisei adicionar as seguintes linhas no meu `application.properties` para o aplicativo 1:

```
spring.application.name=myFirstApp
spring.jmx.default-domain=myFirstApp
```

E para a outra aplicação:

```
spring.application.name=mySecondApp
spring.jmx.default-domain=mySecondApp
```

Inclusive, já usávamos uma outra variável no `application.properties` que fazia as vezes de identificador do aplicativo para recuperar de modo customizado o *tenant routing datasource* do HikariCP, chamada  `mybootapp.appname`. Então, na real, a mudança foi só colocar as seguintes linhas no `application.properties`:

```
spring.application.name=${mybootapp.appname}
spring.jmx.default-domain=${mybootapp.appname}
```

Assim, os `application.properties` ficaram:

```
mybootapp.appname=myFirstApp
spring.application.name=${mybootapp.appname}
spring.jmx.default-domain=${mybootapp.appname}
```

```
mybootapp.appname=mySecondApp
spring.application.name=${mybootapp.appname}
spring.jmx.default-domain=${mybootapp.appname}
```

Essa foi a alternativa com menos mudanças que eu encontrei, sem precisar mexer nas configurações do *container*.